# Writing nested loop in ArnoldC?

Tags: esoteric-languages

ArnoldC is an esoteric language which uses movie lines(dialogues) of Arnold Schwarzenegger. It can be used to do many basic programs. I was trying to write a nested loop in it but was not able to create it. Is it possible to write nested loop in ArnoldC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. You just have to **declare all your loop variables outside** (you can't declare them in), and **initialize them every round** (after the condition variable succeeded). Then you can nest loops before the outer `CHILL` call.

I'll provide an example using a counter-loop, which builds on a flag variable and a counter variable, and print both counters as a four digits number. Comments are after `#`, note they must not be in code (and you can [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPBboMwDIbPyVP41mv7BkuL21glCUpMpx6rrodJCKZqe34W1rUIROAUifj39/t3uNzrpvq4ti3xKkDQ7p3JoJQaz7DTngIbFYA9IlRN8yXProSADGWAsoA366DwbpujcVOSz7q@3Zd0U8Jr81N/3@5jGUFOmCVJ86pJzqW6psplYNodQXlX2uwxvZDiEAvZAWuMvVxRoH@ZFRo9AgUwZyB7IlZMzvbXnTQCNlKgdeVBA6v8KCdb9sElmg4SHPRLtluw@Zx7ZG4QQm9LimVOAjQq6lMZkSej7vYlloIWcaOrWLEnjxls1useM4KPiN35RGoVB/7jzcz6WFHCz6bj5lHp9nsIziAERmVgi9bGrzNWxE5Tnk8/jblX0RHTwBdrMPU/qvsJtDphLEYLjN6QVYxZ2/4C)):

```
IT'S SHOWTIME

# declare outer and inner loop flags
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE loop
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE innerloop
YOU SET US UP @NO PROBLEMO

# declare outer and inner loop counters
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE counter
YOU SET US UP @I LIED
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE innercounter
YOU SET US UP @I LIED

# declare variable for calculations
HEY CHRISTMAS TREE calc
YOU SET US UP @I LIED


# outer loop, using `loop` and `counter`
STICK AROUND loop

    # decrease outer counter
    GET TO THE CHOPPER counter
    HERE IS MY INVITATION counter
    GET UP 1
    ENOUGH TALK

    # prepare inner loop variables - set flag to TRUE and counter to 0
    GET TO THE CHOPPER innerloop
    HERE IS MY INVITATION @NO PROBLEMO
    ENOUGH TALK
    GET TO THE CHOPPER innercounter
    HERE IS MY INVITATION @I LIED
    ENOUGH TALK

    STICK AROUND innerloop

        # decrease inner counter
        GET TO THE CHOPPER innercounter
        HERE IS MY INVITATION innercounter
        GET UP 1
        ENOUGH TALK

        # calculate outer counter * 100 + inner counter
        GET TO THE CHOPPER calc
        HERE IS MY INVITATION counter
        YOU'RE FIRED 100
        GET UP innercounter
        ENOUGH TALK

        # print it
        TALK TO THE HAND calc

        # has inner counter reached 10? if so, set loop variable FALSE
        GET TO THE CHOPPER innerloop
        HERE IS MY INVITATION 10
        LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET innercounter
        ENOUGH TALK
    CHILL

    # has outer counter reached 10? if so, set loop variable FALSE
    GET TO THE CHOPPER loop
    HERE IS MY INVITATION 10
    LET OFF SOME STEAM BENNET counter
    ENOUGH TALK

CHILL

YOU HAVE BEEN TERMINATED
```

Comment: is ArnoldC a Turing complete language